# Simple RPG copy job between to IBM i/AS400 with DDM files hangs after upgrading one system

Tags: ibm-midrange

In the past there were two old AS/400 with V4R5, one as primary for work, one as a backup and dev system.

I wrote a RPG program which simply opens a local DDM file (pointing to the remote machine and file) and a local database file, deletes all local records, iterates (reads) over the remote records and writes them into the local file. This has worked like a charm for years.

Recently I upgraded the primary machine to a more recent box with V7R2. I just copied over a SAVF of the databases' library and restored it without errors. Application ran without any changes. Very nice!

But the copy job running on the old machine, copying from the new machine fails. It just hangs. Wrkactjob shows it's in the state *icfw*. The remote machine's dsplog entries tell that there was a successful connection from the remote box as well as a successful evocation of the local part of the ICF handling. But no data transfer is happening. Then I have to ENDRQS the hanging program on the backup/dev-system via SysReq-menu to get back to qcmd.

Question: **Why is this happening?** Expected behavior is that copying would work as before the migration.

Connectivity between the machines is ok. *Aping* and *strpasthr* work as expected. I browsed though the "work with job" menu on both machines for the associated communication jobs but cannot find any hint what's going wrong. No job log entries so far.

Any hints where I can gather more information are greatly appreciated.

Also, I'm not sure if StackOverflow is the right place to ask, since it's not exactly a programming problem.

Comment: Personally, I'm inclined to give questions like these quite a bit of slack, as far as belonging on Stack Overflow. Because the IBM midrange community is so small, you really need every eyeball you can get, and Stack Overflow has the most eyeballs among the Stack Exchange sites. You could also try subscribing to the midrange.com mailing lists and asking there.

Comment: Maybe you can make a DDMF file from box local to box remote to get database records.  I haven't seen ICF in production since last century.  Not sure if it would work across versions.

Comment: @danny117 In fact, it is a DDM-File, sorry for not reflecting that in my initial problem description. Internally, DDM seems to utilize ICF as communications channel.

Comment: @JohnY Thanks for your understanding and hint, I'll consider that.